# Getting error saying javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved, but worked before

Tags: java

my code was working fine.  Then It stop working and I got a error saying javax.xml.bind cannot be resolved, for the line

```
Calendar Time = javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(data[i].GetTime());
```

I did upgrade my eclipse to oxygen, don't know if that has anything to do with it. Does anybody know how I can fix this or a different way to get a Calendar time for current time and date?

Comment: maybe something wasn't build right. you can try Project ->clean -> clean all projects

Comment: Didn't you remove the import by any chance? `import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;`